# Disable auto-app switch on Xperia Z3 when headphones are plugged in

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, audio, headphones

I know this is supposed to be a feature but it's just plain annoying at this point. Anytime I plug in my headphones, it will automatically open up whatever my primary music player is (PowerAmp right now) and start playing the first audio file it finds.

I seem to remember there was an option in the phone's settings to change this but I can't find it. Checked "Xperia Connectivity" and "Sounds and Notifications".

Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know Sony devices. But in the Android Settings of my LG device, I find it in *Sound › Start Music App* (untick the check-mark there). Can you confirm that for yours?

Comment: A simple macro using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) Can do the trick without root. If that's fine can post an answer

Comment: Are you certain that you've not explicitly enabled this option in PowerAmp itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It ended up not being in Smart Connect as @jkenneth suggested; though I did check that and find everything disabled.

The issue was a setting within PowerAmp itself that was turned on called "audio on headset connect". I disabled that and it fixed my problem.

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions!

Comment: [As suspected](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133507/disable-auto-app-switch-on-xperia-z3-when-headphones-are-plugged-in/134307#comment167625_133507).

Answer (score 2):

It's the Smart Connect app. You can simply toggle it off under the Events tab.
Smart Connect starts up any app or action that you have associated with specific accessory such as Headphones.

Comment: Is this a system app?

Comment: Yes. Smart Connect is a pre-installed application for Sony Xperia smartphones.